# Can't install the VirtualBox Extension Pack-5.1.26 on Debian 9

Tags: debian, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I already tried: closing *all* processes of VirtualBox via KSysGuard and then running: `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.1`, `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1`, `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.1`, `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1`, `sudo vboxconfig`, `virtualbox`. And then adding the extension in the VirtualBox preferences.

This does not get it installed nor does following the command-line instructions for installing it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289686/233262).

Instead I only get VBoxSVC consuming 25% of my CPU. I get the following error when closing VirtualBox after trying that:

> Failed to open the Extension Pack ../Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.26-117224.vbox-extpack.
>   Callee RC: NS_ERROR_ABORT (0x80004004)

and

> Qt WARNING: QWidgetWindow(0x55f9acf151f0, name="UIGlobalSettingsExtensionWindow") must be a top level window.
>   Qt WARNING: No node found for item that was just removed: QUrl("file:///home/user/Downloads/hqdefault.jpg")
>   Qt WARNING: QWidgetWindow(0x55f9ace32ef0, name="UIGlobalSettingsExtensionWindow") must be a top level window.

when doing it via the command-line.

`/var/log/syslog` earlier had (besides some martian packets):

> kernel: SUP_IOCTL_COOKIE: Version mismatch. Requested: 0x2a0000  Min: 0x2a0000  Current: 0x240000

and (`var/log/kern.log`) has:

> kernel: VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
>   kernel: VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
>   kernel: VBoxPciLinuxInit
>   kernel: vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)

[I already this problem earlier but got it working.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389046/how-to-forward-usb-hid-traffic-to-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine) These problems don't look normal.

**Why can't I install the Extension Pack and how can I get it working?**

Comment: Have you installed a new kernel after your last boot?

Comment: No. At least not deliberately. But I installed and uninstalled a driver once but not in the last couple days. What's a good way to check?

Comment: Download the extensions pack from the virtualbox.org system, and login to the root user, I believe all you have to do is to open the extensions pack.

Comment: HaukeLaging That was the reason for why I had to reinstall VirtualBox actually. @mdpc I have sudoers rights. I won't run GUI programs like VirtualBox as root which is good practice. The vbox-extpack file is owned by my user. I know I have to open it which doesn't help if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was: I had to give execute permissions for the owner to the .vbox-extpack file. For some reason it had execution rights unchecked. (I also had this problem when downloading the file via wget instead of via the browser.)

---

I then had to do [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250573/virtualbox-kernel-modules-do-not-match-the-version-of-virtualbox/873471#873471) to get VMs working again. Until then I got this error (which is also the reason I reinstalled VirtualBox):

> RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)
>
> The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.
>
> where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.